# Getting around a type-erasure in pattern-matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I am trying to work around a type erasure in pattern matching. Assuming:

```
import java.io._

trait Serializer[V] {
  def save(os: OutputStream, v: V): Unit
  def load(in: InputStream): V
}

trait HasSerializer[V] { def serializer: Serializer[V] }
```

How can I get this to compile without warning and without `asInstanceOf`:

```
def test[V](os: OutputStream, v: V): Unit = v match {
  case hs: HasSerializer[V] => hs.serializer.save(os, v)
  case _                    => ???
}
```

? `test` is called with a value from a map and there is no means to provide a class manifest.

Any fancy extractor trick maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the question has kind of a wrong precondition (as I just realize) -- we can take `Serializer` apart into a serializer and a deserializer. Obviously, when I have an instance of `V`, my use case is *serialization*, and that doesn't require `V` as a return type. Thus

```
trait Serializer { def save(os: OutputStream): Unit }
```

would suffice, and any type can mix that in. And do:

```
def testSer[V](os: OutputStream, v: V): Unit = v match {
  case s: Serializer => s.save(os)
  case _ => new ObjectOutputStream(os).writeObject(v)
}
```

And for deserialization, we would either provide the deserializer along with the construction of a `Ref[V]`, or rely on class lookup through `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: Well "any type can mix that it" is not true, of course. The problem still holds for existing types, let's say (as in Alex' example) we want to provide a serializer for `Int`...

Answer (score 4):

If you can make Serializer an abstract class instead, you can give it a Manifest as an implicit constructor parameter, and use that to get the concrete class at construction, then use it later for dynamic type checks.

```
import java.io._

abstract class Serializer[V: Manifest] {
  def save(os: OutputStream, v: V): Unit
  def load(in: InputStream): V
  val clazz = manifest[V].erasure
}

val ser = new Serializer[Int] {
  def save(os: OutputStream, v: Int) {
    os.write((v.toString + "\n").getBytes)
  }

  def load(in: InputStream) = {
    val line = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)).readLine()
    line.toInt
  }
}

ser.clazz //  java.lang.Class[_] = int
```

Comment: But how would I find out if an instance of V provides a Serializer? I still don't see how I would perform the check in the `test` method without eventually having to cast to `V`?

Comment: If you can't use type classes because the values are essentially untyped, I'm not sure you can avoid having some registry and lookup mechanism.  I'd be happy to see another approach though!

Comment: I don't need a registry, as I can match against `HasSerializer[ _ ]` and then cast safely to `HasSerializer[ V ]`, but that's exactly what I don't want to do. `V` is passed around a few times between different interfaces, passing around a `ClassManifest` is simply no option, Scala just honestly sucks with this concept of 'reification'...